# deleted file off server, file still accessible

Tags: javascript, caching, filezilla

Ive done this a million times but this time its having its way with me. I usually work on joomla sites and this one is a drupal site so maybe theres something to that.

In filezillla, i uploaded scripts.js.

I noticed an error in my script. I fix it and reupload it. No failed transfer. I check to make sure the fix works, but find the old version of the code still there.

Ok, I clear chromes cache, reload. Old code still there.

I delete the file off the server. Old code still there. (!!)

I completely barf all over the javascript. Should throw errors. I upload it. Old code still there and no errors.

I change the name of the new scripts.js to scripts2.js and upload it. I navigate to that file via browser URL. Not found. Its right there in the server though, uploaded and refreshed the filezilla pane. Filezilla says its there. Browser says its not. Copied / pasted the path. Theres no spelling mistakes. New file being reported as 404 by browser.

I completely delete project folder off server and reupload. Old code still there. Starting to go nuts.

This has got to be some sort of caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "clear all caches" function in Drupal. It should be under  Settings -> Performance. Try that.

Comment: that must be an admin thing, cause theres no option for settings here.edit : yep, on my test server I have that option. I swear, Ive never been so hamstrung on a single project! First had to deal with malformed XML, then a cross domain issue, even getting these drupal creds took 2 weeks. I feel like that guy in office space lol!! Thank you for your answer, gonna mark is as the correct one since it lead me there.

Comment: Yeah, it is an admin thing. You could try restarting the server, if you have access to it. Also, sometimes Drupal instances are hooked up to external caches, like Memcached, which could be holding on to the data.